# Sharing data among websites

Tags: python, websites, flask

I manage one middle sized website that uses Flask and PostgresSQL on the backend and some JS with Angular and Jinja2 templates on the fronted.

Now we're going to create a second website that will be similar to the first one, most of the models and tables could be shared amont the 2, just simply put, both are used for scheduling courses and classes but with different branding and audience.

Thus, my idea was to use a single DB, probably 3 docker containers, one for each Flask app and another one for Postgres and have them use the same tables.

My concerns are as follows:

1. How to reuse accounts? Should I create my own Identity Provider and use OpenID for the login part ob both sites? Should I just use plain old user / password as we do have on first site but now with 2?
2. Ideally, both sites won't interfere with records from tables from one site or another, but I'm not sure I can guarantee ACID transactions having 2 different backends hitting the same DB? Not sure, neved did this before
3. Currently we have a small API, I might make the second site frontend be communicating with just the API so it's agnostic of the backend..I might not even need a second backend at all in this case?
4. Is this a good idea or should I just use another DB and have some rsync between the 2 for the tables that need to be synced?

Comment: thanks for the edits πάντα ῥεῖ, I wonder why the downvotes...I thought this site was to share architectural and design concerns...

Comment: Should this be one application that serves content via multiple domains, or separate websites that share some components? Or something in between? I can't tell you what to do because I don't know what your goals are, but the proper architecture will depend dramatically on your goals.  E.g. perhaps you want to have separate sites that just share user accounts, in which case creating a separate microservice could be sensible. Avoid sharing one database across multiple services or applications.

Comment: @amon these will be different domains. Still trying to think if I need another backend or I can serve the 2 sites using a single Flask application. The old one is not agnostic of the backend because it uses a lot of Jinja but the new one, I can make it just communicating via API calls I guess. On the other hand, it's not just the Users table that I need to share, but more, like courses, sessions, etc.

Comment: How separate should those sites be? Is it allowed that a user of site A sees content created by a user of site B? If I create an account on site A, can I use that same account to login to site B? Or create linked accounts?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Hey Bart, not all the content from site A (the old one) should be accessible to site B (the new one), only courses and sessions. And yes, users should be shared among sites

Comment: I'm counting 6 questions in this question... maybe try to narrow your focus down to one or two concerns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two sites offer essentially the same services on behalf of a single organisation to two different audience groups and the difference between the sites is mainly in branding and some supplementary features that makes each site more attractive to its respective target audience, then you should aim to use shared components as much as possible.

That would start with a shared database, but is one or both sites can use an API then you can even use a shared backend. The advantage is that common functionality has to be built only once and bugfixes also need to be applied only once.

And if users are shared between the sites, you can just use the same login mechanism (appropriately branded) on each site and authenticate against the Users table in that single database.

---

Regarding your question about ACID transactions, those are provided by the database itself, regardless of how many backends (or backend instances) connect to that database.

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, I'm gonna make the second site communicate via just the API we already have, so it's nothing else but another API client. Thanks Bart!